# npm install -g ionic not installing in windows 8.1

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm new to ionic framework and getting error when im trying to install ionic.

I have installed apache-ant, nodejs, cordova but when i was trying to install ionic then it throws error as follows.

OS windows 8.1 64 bit.

Please guide me to install this ionic.

```
\node-sass\build\binding.sln" (default target) (1) ->
(_src_\libsass target) ->
  ..\..\src\libsass\include\sass/base.h(18): fatal error C1083: Cannot open inc
lude file: 'stdbool.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\guru.ramachandran\A
ppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln]
  ..\..\src\libsass\include\sass/base.h(18): fatal error C1083: Cannot open inc
lude file: 'stdbool.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\guru.ramachandran\A
ppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln]
  c:\users\guru.ramachandran\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_module
s\node-sass\src\libsass\src\units.hpp(10): error C2668: 'acos' : ambiguous call
 to overloaded function [C:\Users\guru.ramachandran\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_mo
dules\ionic\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln]
  c:\users\guru.ramachandran\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_module
s\node-sass\src\libsass\src\ast.hpp(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include
 file: 'unordered_map': No such file or directory [C:\Users\guru.ramachandran\A
ppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln]
  c:\users\guru.ramachandran\appdata\roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_module
s\node-sass\src\libsass\src\ast.hpp(12): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include
 file: 'unordered_map': No such file or directory [C:\Users\guru.ramachandran\A
ppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln]
  ..\..\src\libsass\include\sass/values.h(5): fatal error C1083: Cannot open in
clude file: 'stdbool.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\guru.ramachandran\
AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic\node_modules\node-sass\build\binding.sln
```

Comment: try using **sudo npm install ionic -g**

Comment: @MohanGopi that command is not available for windows.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is about `node-gyp` module, which requires VS2013-VS2015 to build components at this time, in their `README` file, they say

> Option 1
>
> Install all the required tools and configurations using Microsoft's
>   windows-build-tools using
>
> `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`
>
> from an elevated PowerShell or CMD.exe (run as
>   Administrator).
>
> Option 2
>
> Install tools and configuration manually:
>
> Visual C++ Build Environment:
>
> Option 1: Install Visual C++ Build Tools using the Default Install
>   option.
>
> Option 2: Install Visual Studio 2015 (or modify an existing
>   installation) and select Common Tools for Visual C++ during setup.
>   This also works with the free Community and Express for Desktop
>   editions.
>
> [Windows Vista / 7 only] requires .NET Framework 4.5.1 Install
>   Python 2.7 (v3.x.x is not supported), and run npm config set python
>   python2.7 (or see below for further instructions on specifying the
>   proper Python version and path.)
>
> Launch cmd, `npm config set msvs_version 2015`

Source: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp